# Wrong color format or a defective camera?

Tags: opencv, rgb, video-capture, color-scheme, yuv

I am using the following `OpenCV` code to access video feed from a camera (lsusb command in Jetson TX1 terminal lists the camera as Pixart Imaging, Inc.).

**Code:**

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main()
{
        cv::VideoCapture cap(1);
        if(!cap.isOpened())
        {       
                std::cout << "Input error\n";
                return -1;
        }

        cv::namedWindow("Video Feed", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        for(;;)
        {
                cv::Mat frame;
                cap >> frame;
                std::cout << "Type: " << frame.type() << "\n";
                //cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_YUV2RGB);
                //cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size2i(256, 144));
                cv::imshow("Video Feed", frame);        
                if (cv::waitKey(10) == 27)
                {
                        break;
                }
        }       
        cv::destroyAllWindows();
        return 0;
}
```

The screeenshots of the video feed can be seen below:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to identify the color format of the camera and convert it to `RGB`. I have tried different color formats, but I focused mainly on `YUV` to `RGB` conversion as shown below (this line is commented out in the above code): `cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_YUV2RGB);`

I have also tried different variants of YUV as listed [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0aa4a7f0ecf2e94150699e48c79139ee12). However, I haven't received any result close to a normal `RGB` image.

I am also getting the following message on the terminal:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

1) Is this just a defective camera?

2) Are there any tests/ approaches to identify and rectify the problem?

**Edit:**
I have added a new picture to give an idea of what the actual color of the shirt of the person closer to the camera is:
[image]

Comment: I'd say it would be much more useful to print out some simple [ColorChecker chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColorChecker) and take pictures of that, so you can compare against known target (I honestly don't know what colour that shirt is supposed to be). Could be a messed up color balance. Can you view the video with correct colours using something other than OpenCV (say some existing app)? And do you really not know what specific model of a camera you have?

Comment: It gave similar video feed when checked via vlc. I don't know what the specific model of the camera is. Even the person who gave this camera to me does not. I will try the colorChecker chart and update the question.

Comment: `imshow()` from opencv expects BGR, not RGB images, so you should use `YUV2BGR` if you're going to display the image using `imshow()`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I will try that.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds `YUV2BGR` did not work.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: No. I haven't. I am proceeding with a new camera.

Comment: If you can make some data available I can take a look at this